# What alignment would best match my character?

Tags: character-creation, alignment

I know the question sounds subjective, but literally any outside opinion would be better than nothing.

I don't have a lot of experience with D&D, I have yet to play a single game because I could never (until now) find a group of people to play with.

I'm thinking of making a fighter with a tendency to take trophies from enemies and if possible use said trophy as a weapon..
and I'm not talking about "this is my hat now" kind of trophies..
but more the "I rip off the golems arm and use it as a club" kind of trophies.
The Alien vs Predator kind.

considering ripping a dead tieflings horns off to use as daggers doesn't sound very lawfull, I was thinking "that sounds pretty chaotic if you ask me"

and I don't like being a massive d*ckhead or a goody two shoes, so in terms of morality I'd say neutral.

the way I keep describing him to myself it sounds like Chaotic Neutral, but I've read that alot of DMs don't like CN because people tend to play CN as the "I do what I want" kind of alignment.

while this is not entirely wrong...
I tend to do what I want as long as it doesnt hurt anyone... so no burning down taverns or stabbing quest givers in the back.
removing a corpses shin bones so I could later grind them into shanks "technically" doesn't hurt anyone since they're already dead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is off-topic. See this meta on alignment: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/what-kinds-of-alignment-questions-are-on-topic However, you might be able to get some feedback if you try [chat].

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Chaotic/Lawful is not only about about *what* a character does but also about *why*.

Does he do this because he want to intentionally defy social norms regarding sanctity of dead bodies? Then he is chaotic.

Does he do this because he is following some cultural or personal code of conduct which requires him to take trophies from his enemies? Then he is lawful.

Comment: my character would not cut off a tail just for the sake of defiling the dead no.. a respect for the dead is still something I myself (and my character by extension) somewhat value..
but defying social norm does sound like something my character would do..

my main reasoning at first was "for the sh*ts and gigglez" but I felt that was a bit inadequate of a motivation so i'm trying to flesh it out a bit